# object existance not being recognised in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, if-statement, null

I have the following script:

```
function canLogin($mail, $password) {
    if( isset($mail, $password) ) {
        $login = dbFind('users', array("mail" => (string)"$mail", "pass" => (string)"$password"), true);
        var_dump($login);
        if($login)
            { return (string)$login['_id']; }
            else { return false; }
    } else { return false; }
}
```

which function dbFind is the following:

```
function dbFind($collIn, $obj, $one = false) {
    global $db;

    $collection = $db->$collIn;

    if($one == true)
        return $collection->findOne($obj);
        else return $collection->find($obj);
}
```

now, as you can notice from the first snippet of code, I am using var_dump to see the content of the $login variable and afterwards check if it is set or not.

When I have a right login, the var_dump returns the correct object from the db, otherwise it returns NULL. The problem is that in the if statement just after the var_dump always returns false!

What I am missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: update: it seems to work if I use if($login != false) but... why is that? false is different from null! and if they are not, it should then just work!

Comment: Have you tried `if($login !== false){ }` or `if($login !== NULL){ }` or `if(gettype($login) == 'object'){ } `?

Comment: Because of the [comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), if you'd have used `$login !== false` you'd had other result.

Comment: Please go and lookup how the = !== == === !== operators work

Comment: using `if ($someVar)` doesn't do type && value checking, but checks for _falsy_ values: `''`, `0`, `array()`, `null` and god knows what else will evaluate to false. Try to be as specific as possible: `if (is_object($foo))`, `if (is_array($foo))` or even `if (!empty($foo))`, to check for type and value: `if ($foo !== false)` (three logical operators: `===` or `!==`)

Comment: none of the above is working. the result from the dbFind functions are either NULL or `array(5) { ["_id"]=> object(MongoId)#8 (1) { ["$id"]=> string(24) "50d19fed9cc2318521000001" } ["mail"]=> string(16) "foo@gmail.com" ["pass"]=> string(6) "123456" ["last"]=> int(1355915245) ["ip"]=> string(12) "1.1.10.86" }`

Comment: A database return should never evaluate to false, and it does not for me. Only falsey values eval to false and a full array does not. Take away that `(string)` bit a sec, see if that doesn't return false.

Comment: @Sammaye: In fact, it does not evaluate to false, but to NULL, that translates into "no results" - the (string) casting does not influence the return of the variable: it can be seen by the var_dump result.

Comment: I thought your var_dump occurs before the if as such if there is an error in casting to string in the if it can actually return false but yea I didn't see your first comment, hmmm. Well I cannot replicate your behaviour that's for sure. Which MongoDB driver version is this? And PHP version? I should also note that `if($login)` the else of this does translate to false in PHP, it is just that `null` and `false` are the same values in a loose comparison in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
If (isset($login)){
   //do what you need
}
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to be working... read the comment on my question.

Comment: `isset` checks for variable existance. The variable `$login` always exists in this case.

Comment: If using such a broad "net" then rather use `!empty()` instead... `$string = '';` is set, but empty, as is `$obj = NULL`

Answer (score 0):

```
if($login != NULL){
return (string)$login['_id'];
}else{
return false;
}
```

I had such an issue and this worked and it's working.

Comment: OP has answered this in the above comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `if` statement to something like:

```
if (is_array($login) &&  array_key_exists('_id', $login) && $login['_id'] instanceof MongoId)
{
    //the array_key_exists check could be omitted, but is there just in case
    return (string) $login['_id'];
}
```

You can omit the first two checks and use `!empty($login['_id']) && $login['_id'] instanceof MongoId`, but that *might* issue warnings (not sure).
BTW: try setting your ini file to `E_STRICT | E_ALL`, maybe that'll give you some more clues as to what's going wrong.

From what you've posted in your comment, and looking at your code, this line: `return (string)$login['_id'];` is actually casting an object to a string. The result looks like this:

```
array(5) { ["_id"]=> object(MongoId)#8 (1) //<-- OBJECT
    { ["$id"]=> string(24) "50d19fed9cc2318521000001" } 
}
```

And you're using the `(string)` cast, <strike>that just doesn't feel right</strike> As Sammaye pointed out, that should work
. You're casting too much BTW: `"$foo"` casts `$foo` to a string, because of the double quotes, no need for an extra cast... but that's not the point... Anyway, try this:

```
return $login['id']->{'$id'};//need the single quotes, the property NAME is $id, not id
```

See the docs on the [mongoid class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php) for more details on the methods/properties, and headaches...

PS: it might be cleaner to use the getter method:

```
$login['_id']->getPID();//returns an int, not a string, though
```

Good luck, happy coding

Comment: the thing is that the compiler is not even getting to that point: it fails at the IF statement just above that line!

Comment: You CAN cast the objectId to string, it is perfectly legitimate due to implementing the __toString magic correctly. It was a wild guess by me, nothing more.

Comment: @Sammaye: Fair enough, didn't look at the `__toString` method, but it does return the id as a string... you're absolutely right about that. I'll edit my answer, and add another suggestion for the OP